# This code is supposed to output the number of times a word starts with a letter from the alphabet, but just displays zero for each one

Tags: vb.net, console-application

This code is supposed to output the number of times a word starts with a letter from the alphabet, but just displays zero for each one
I get no errors, but just a text file with all of the letters and zero for each one.

When pressing the debug button, it appears to do nothing. Here's the code

```
Imports System.IO


Module Module1

Sub Main()
    Dim myArray As New List(Of String)
    Using myReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(".\myFile.txt")
        'telling VB that we're using a StreamREader, read a line at a time
        Dim myLine As String
        myLine = myReader.ReadLine 'assigns the line to String Variable myLine
        Do While (Not myLine Is Nothing)
            myArray.Add(myLine) 'adding it to the list of words in the array
            Console.WriteLine(myLine)
            myLine = myReader.ReadLine
        Loop
    End Using
    SortMyArray(myArray) 'Calls the new SubRoutine => SortMyArray, passing through the parameter myArray, 
    'created back on line 7 that stores all of the lines read from the text file.
    'Console.ReadLine()
    wordCount(myArray)
End Sub

Sub SortMyArray(ByVal mySort As List(Of String))
    Dim Tmp As String, writePath As String = ".\sorted.txt"
    Dim max As Integer = mySort.Count - 1
    Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(writePath)

    For Loop1 = 0 To max - 1
        For Loop2 = Loop1 + 1 To max
            If mySort(Loop1) > mySort(Loop2) Then
                Tmp = mySort(Loop2)
                mySort(Loop2) = mySort(Loop1)
                mySort(Loop1) = Tmp

            End If
        Next
        myWriter.WriteLine(mySort.Item(Loop1).ToString())
    Next
    myWriter.Dispose()
End Sub
Sub wordCount(ByVal stringArray As List(Of String))
    Dim alphabet As String = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz", myString As String
    Dim writePath As String = ".\counted.txt"
    Dim myWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(writePath)
    Dim countOf(25) As Integer, Max As Integer = stringArray.Count - 1

    For Loop1 = 0 To 25
        myString = alphabet.Substring(Loop1, 1)
        For Loop2 = 0 To Max
            If stringArray(Loop2).Substring(0, 1) = myString Then
                countOf(Loop1) += 1
            End If
        Next
        myWriter.WriteLine(myString & " occured " & countOf(Loop1) & " times ")
    Next
    myWriter.Dispose()
End Sub


End Module
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Did you put break points in? What do you mean the debug button appears to do nothing?

Comment: Pressing the debug button doesn't launch the console mode, it's like something is broken. I haven't tried break points yets.

Comment: What is the format of the input file? Is it one word only per line?

Comment: I recommend comparing everything as either lowercase or uppercase, so that "Apple" in the file will add 1 to the count for "a". You might also need to initialise the `countOf` array to all 0's.

Comment: It's worth noting your solution has complexity `O(mn)`, where `m` is the number of letters in the alphabet and `n` is the number of lines in the input file. You can do it in `O(n)` time by getting the character code of the first character, subtracting the character code for "a" and then using that as the index in `countOf` to increment.